# classnotfoundexception when running hadoop streaming(version - 2.6.5) for python

Tags: hadoop, classnotfoundexception, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

Whenever I am trying to run this piece of coding for executing map-reduce code in python I am getting a **classnotfoundexception**. I am currently using hadoop-2.6.5 .

Input:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop1/share/hadoop/tools/sources/hadoop-streaming-2.6.5-test-sources.jar \
-input /wordcount/input/student_list.txt \ 
-output /wordcount/output/student_list_py.txt \
-mapper /home/hduser/wordcount_py/mapper.py \ 
-reducer /home/hduser/wordcount_py/reducer.py
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -input
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I am new to Big Data and Hadoop. Kindly Help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong jar to run a Hadoop Streaming job. The streaming jar is in the path `share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.5.jar` under the Hadoop installation directory. Also note `-output` must be a non-existent directory and not a file name.

Try this command,

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.5.jar \
-input /wordcount/input/student_list.txt \ 
-output /wordcount/output/ \
-mapper /home/hduser/wordcount_py/mapper.py \ 
-reducer /home/hduser/wordcount_py/reducer.py \
-file /home/hduser/wordcount_py/mapper.py \
-file /home/hduser/wordcount_py/reducer.py
```

Comment: Thanks..bt still I am getting error like this : 17/04/30 13:58:43 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [/home/hduser/wordcount_py/mapper.py, /home/hduser/wordcount_py/reducer.py] [] /tmp/streamjob6033330482697904585.jar tmpDir=null
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /./mapper.py (Permission denied)

Comment: 1) Is the path of mapper and reducer files correct? 2) Do you have Permissions to it?  3) Does the Python files have the shebang line?